# Maven: How to decide Spring Data Elasticsearch pom version based on Spring framework version?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, version, spring-data-elasticsearch

My company is using spring framework `4.3.20.RELEASE` and maven, now we are going to integrate Elasticsearch. Sadly we cannot use Spring Boot to manage the versions.

How could I find out which `Spring Data Elasticsearch` pom version is best suited? Is there a version matrix? How would you find out the most compatible version in these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version matrix for Spring Data Elasticsearch (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.1.2/reference/html/#preface.versions) does not contain the Spring Core dependencies - I'll have to fix that.

When checking mvnrepository.com I find that Spring 4.3.20.RELEASE is from October 15th 2018 - pretty old.

The last Spring Data release train on Spring 4.3 was Ingalls (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/wiki/Release-Train-Ingalls) and that contained  Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1 which in turn used the Elasticsearch client libraries from Elasticsearch 2.3.3.

I honestly doubt that the Elasticsearch you are using is this old.

I think you first should upgrade you Spring dependency to a current 5 before trying to integrate Spring Data.

Comment: Sure, I will try upgrading Spring, I might not be able to do that as nobody in my company wants to changes things as long as the old system works. Well, at least I know which version to use if we have to stay with Spring4. Thank you!

Comment: that a system works, is not enough. Tell them that these old versions are beyond end of lifecycle and there won't be bugfixes, security fixes and a lot of missing features.